# How to display usermeta on front end of site

Tags: options

Question:

First example:
when getting options from the database for a plugin. You'd use
     `get_option['plugin_optios']`.

My question is how do you 'GET' data from another table? Like wp_usemeta.

I want to grab the 'usermeta' and display it on the front of the site. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$user_id = 9;
$key = 'last_name';
$single = true;
$user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
echo '<p>The '. $key . ' value for user id ' . $user_id . ' is: ' . $user_last . '</p>'; 
?>
```

More information here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta